# When will be a suspended (not at the center of the mass) symmetric rotating gyroscope in stable or instable position?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gyroscopes

The original question is what is in the title. I'm not sure about the answer so here is my solution, please correct me If I am wrong:

It is known for a gyroscope what is in a homogenous gravity field that the $V_{eff}=Mgs\cos(\theta)+\frac{(N_z-N_3\cos\theta)^2}{2A\sin^2(\theta)}$ is the effective potential. Where $N_z$ is the angular momentum in the direction of the $Z$ axis in the lab's system, $N_3$ is the angular momentum in the direction of the symmetry axis in the gyroscope's system, the angular mass is the
$$I=
\left(\begin{matrix}A&0&0\\
0 &B &0\\
0 & 0 & C
\end{matrix}
\right)$$, $\theta$ is one of the Euler-angles, $M$ is the mass of the gyroscope, $g$ the gravitational acceleration and $s$ is the distance along the symmetry axis from the center of mass to the suspension point ($s<0$).

We have to inspect the case when $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$. In these cases the gyroscope is in equilibrium for every $\omega$ but at $\theta=\pi$ it is unstable and for $\theta=0$ it is unstable too for an angular speed of the gyroscope around the symmetry axis ($\omega_3$) greater than $0$.

And now have a look at the effective potential. We want to find the equilibrium state for a given $\theta$ with finding the $\omega_3$, so derived the potential respect to $\omega_3$ and where the derivative is equal to $0$, we get $\omega_3$ at the equilibrium state. ($N_3=C\omega_3$)
$$V_{eff}'(\omega_3)=\frac{N_z-C^2\omega_3\cos^2(\theta)}{A\sin^2{\theta}}$$
$$\omega_3= \frac{N_z}{C^2\cos^2(\theta)}$$
From the second derivative we can this is an unstable state.

We have to notice that we don't want to divide with zero, so we have to handle the $\theta=\frac\pi2$ differently. We only can get an equilibrium state at this case if the $N_z=0$. In our case it is impossible.